# Can I force a table caption to be a figure caption?

Tags: floats, captions

If I fill a table with figures, and give an caption, it is by default named `Table XXX`, but can I force it to be a `Figure XXX` caption? How? Thanks

Comment: Instead of wrapping the `tabular` with `table`, use `figure`.

Comment: Yes, place it inside a `figure` environment rather than a `table`.

Comment: Can you use a figure environment instead of table? Do you load the package `caption` or do you use a KOMA class? Then you can work with `\captionof{figure}` or `\captionsetup{type=figure}` (only caption).